# Change screen math font in LyX

Tags: lyx

In LyX, under Tools -> Preferences -> Look & Feel -> Screen Fonts, I cannot find an option to change the default screen font used to display math.

Is there some way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

The three screen fonts you see there apply to both text and math. Most math will show up in the Roman one but the other two are used for math in \mathsf and \mathtt regions.

If you were hoping for a way to change the math font independently of the text font, unfortunately I don't think that there's a way. However, you could turn on instant preview in Look & Feel -> Graphics, which will make the equations show up in the true font that they will be typeset in (apart from while you're editing the equation). This is quite a useful thing to do anyway; I wish they'd turn it on by default.

Comment: +1 I hadn't noticed that screen fonts applied to both text and math. However, I'd much prefer to change them the fonts independently;

Comment: @niels I don't think you can do that. All display fonts are configured in `Tools > Settings > Screen Fonts`.

Comment: As @landroni said, I don't think that's possible. But you could try my workaround of using instant preview. Then the display math font is whatever the output document's true math font is (except when your cursor is inside the equation). You can change that in document settings.

Comment: @niels Agreed. The instant preview is a useful workaround, hence my +1.